# On login redirect to different homepage if user is using a mobile

Tags: redirect, mobile

I have a responsive website which is accessed via login only. When the user logs in they are taken to 'Page 1' (and it is set as the front page).

I would like mobile users to be redirected to 'Page 2' on login. I've found a function which checks if they're using a mobile but it won't let me access 'Page 1' as it redirects back to 'Page 2'.

This is the function:

```
function so16165211_mobile_home_redirect(){
  if( wp_is_mobile() && is_front_page() ){
     wp_redirect( 'http://www.mywebsite.com/page-2' ); 
      exit;
  }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'so16165211_mobile_home_redirect' );
```

Is it possible to modify this so it only redirects the mobile user once they've logged in as I'd still like them to access 'Page 1'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [login_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/login_redirect/) hook. For example:

```
add_filter('login_redirect', function($to, $request, $user)
{
    if ( wp_is_mobile() ) $to = admin_url('profile.php');

    return $to;
}, PHP_INT_MAX, 3);
```